# Office.js: Outlook for Mac Add-In - custom properties not saved for existing object

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

So in my Outlook Add-In (Office.js) I'm setting some custom properties to an calendar event, using following code:

```
        const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync((result) => {
            const props = result.value;
            props.set("my_prop", "some value");
            props.saveAsync((saveResult) => {
                console.log("SAVE_CUSTOM_PROP", saveResult);
            });
        });
```

And it works fine, on a newly created event, after I save it and open it again, I can access the custom property value using following code:

```
        const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync((result) => {
            const props = result.value;
            const my_data = props.get("my_prop");
            console.log(my_data);
        });
```

**However** when I open an **existing event**, with or without custom properties being set, the custom properties I'm setting doesn't get saved after the user saves the event.

If I open the event again it doesn't have the new custom properties, it has either none (if none wasn't set), or the old values which were set when the event was newly created (not yet saved).

It works as expected in Outlook for PC and OWA.

Outlook for Mac Add-in support bug? I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you see in the console log when saveAsync() on existing event? Do you have OutlookSpy for Outlook on Windows? If so, can you check the calendar event has your custom property changed?

Comment: It's Outlook **for Mac** so `saveAsync` is not supported on an event and no OutlookSpy. On Windows it works as expected. When I get the custom property after I set it - it's there. But when I save the event, and open it again, my change is gone.

Comment: CustomProperties.SaveAsync() available for 1.0 level API and you are saying it is not supported on event type of messages? You said you are able to set/save them for new event, are you? When I said use OutlookSpy, I mention for Windows Desktop Outlook, indeed. Use it for the same event and look if your property has been changed when you save the event on Mac.

Comment: You wrote >>saveAsync() on existing event<< `saveAsync` on event is not available on Mac, it's available on the `CustomProperties` object indeed, but that's saving the custom properties only on the offline opened object, not on the server. If I call `saveAsync` on the CustomProperties, the property is on the event, but when I save it and reopen, they are not there, and not on the server (not visible from OWA or Outlook on PC)

Comment: This sounds like a bug. What is the Outlook build number you're testing against?

Comment: It's the latest 15.33 version on Mac (official, not insider). Where can I get some help regarding the roadmap for fixing such bug? It's a roadblocker for our big release.

Comment: Could you provide the build number as well? There was a similar bug that I believe was fixed in build 20170122. Just want to confirm if this is the same issue or not.

Comment: Build number is 170409, so a newer build I guess - maybe a kickback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally issue resolved, today Outlook for Mac **15.34** is out, and it fixes that issue.

So it was a bug on Outlook for Mac office.js support.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I believe I have a solution for you: When You set your CustomProperties and save them, in same time, get some visible message field, for example "subject"; modify it with API, for example set it to the same subject + white-space. After save the event itself as user would do. At this time message will have status "dirty" and will be actually saved, along with your custom properties, I hope. Let me know if this work around works.

Comment: Interesting approach, was hoping it will work, but unfortunately it's not, my add-in is modifing the description field after each save of a custom property, additionally I tried to modify the subject by hand and then save - still nothing. The modified description and subject fields get saved, but the custom property still has the same old property :( Nevertheless thanks for trying to find a workaround :)

Comment: Well let me think, I may ask you a couple of more questions later. For now tell me when you save event with modified by hand subject and look at this even in OWA, do you see the even changed? I mean the message was sync with Exchange? Unfortunately I don't have the mac to try myself.

Comment: Yes exactly, I write some custom data in those properties, but I set also them in the description in a formated way. When I save the event anywhere (Outlook PC, OWA), everything gets saved. But when I save it on Outlook for Mac, the description is saved, but the custom properties are not.

Comment: Sorry Alek, at this point I am out of ideas and understand there something going on with API for Outlook on Mac. It would be beneficial for you if somebody from Microsoft step up, but I know they not too often have Mac handy to try as well.

Comment: @alekkowalczyk Alek, would you mind to try one more thing for me on your Mac ... can you use CustomProperties.remove() with following saveAsync() and observe the result. This is just to verify the issue with "saveAsync" and not with "set" which you used to update your properties. Also can you use "set" on existing event and add new property. Is this new property will be there? I am getting out of ideas, looks like it is really buggy.

Comment: Just did this check, it's the same behavior, the custom property gets removed in the event after `saveAsync()`, that is - if I get it again it's not there anymore. But when I click `Save&Close` on that event, and open it again - the custom property is back there.

Answer (score 0):

I used Mac Outlook latest build and able to save Custom Property for an appointment that you do not own (sent by someone else) but unable to set the custom property if you edit the appointment that you own (i.e you are the owner of the meeting) - Do you see the same behaviour ?

Comment: Appointment sent by someone else is on a read-only form, my add-in doesn't have a panel for such form, only for compose form which is used to edit an appointment that I own. So for the part of the owned appointment it's the same behavior, unless it's a newly created appointment - it's like "create" function saves the custom properties, but "save existing" not. Dunno about the appointments which I don't own though.